# How can I find the explicit formula?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How can I find the explicit formula for $F(x)$ if $F$ is defined as:
$ F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f $   for $0 \leq x \leq 4$ where

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
                                   2 & \text{0 $\leq x \leq 2$} \\
                                   -1 & \text{2 $< x \leq 4$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Find $F(x)$ for $0\le x\le2$, then find the $F(x)$ for $2<x\le4$ with the identity $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\int_0^2f(t)\,dt+\int_2^xf(t)\,dt$.

Answer (score 0):

F(X)= $\int_0^x f(t)dt = \int_0^x(2)dt=2x\,\,for\, 0\le x \le2 $
$$F(X)=4+\int_2^x f(t)dt=4+(x-2)(-1)=6-x$$
$$ for \ 2\le x \le 4 $$